# using specifics when making linear regression models in r

Tags: r, binary-data, regression

I am not really sure what catagory this goes under but I have a data set and I want to test the association between test results (response) and 3 catagorical variables (SEX) and (INFARCTS) and (LACUNE) these 3 are all binary

so essentially I want to produce a linear model of test results for Males and females that have Infarcts

and

test results for males and females that lacunes

i dont know if this makes sense but any help would be great
thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1                            please check this link on how to ask a good question. i would be glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's should work. If you have more then two categories you need to dummy code your categories. But with only two just use 0 and 1 and run the regression normally as long as your dependent variable is continuous. If the dependent variable is binary as well, you'll need to do a logistic regression.